# Intent problems in Android

Tags: android

I have two Activities in my Android Application, Activity A and Activity B. Activity A triggers Activity B by an Intent and then when I'm in Activity B, which is a listView I click on a particular item and pass data back to Activity A by using putExtras() as part of my Intent when going back to Activity A.

The problem that I have is that when I select on an item from the listView that I want to pass back to Activity A the application crashes, but when I use a normal intent, which doesn't pass any data across Activities it works fine.

The code below demonstrates what I am trying to do.

Activity A

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    private String myString;
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
      Button selectEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.events);

      myString = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getString("myKey"):null;

     if(myIntentString == null)
     {
         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

         myString = extras != null ? extras.getString("myKey"):null;
     }

     selectEvent.setText(myString);

     selectEvent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                ActivityA.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
   }
}


public class ActivityB extends ListActivity 
{
private String selection;
private final int SECONDARY_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
String[] listOfNames = {"Peter", "Paul", "John"};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.events);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfData));
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);

            myIntent.putExtra("myKey", selection);

            startActivityForResult(myIntent, SECONDARY_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
}
```

Your help would be most appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Check out the logs with logcat.  Sounds like a null pointer.

Comment: I'm betting on null pointer as well. If you can post the logs maybe we can figure out exactly where it is happening.

Comment: I see no `onActivityResult` in Activity A.  Can't do this without that method.

Comment: Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) an answer if one of them helped.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing two concepts here.

1) How to get data passed via an Intent in an Activity

2) How to return data from an Activity to the calling Activity.

You want #2.

user432209 is correct about the lack of onActivityResult function in Activity A.

But since you invoked Activity B with `startActivity` instead of `startActivityForResult`, that's understandable.

You want to start ActivityB via `startActivityForResult` and handle the returned data in ActivityA's `onActivityResult` method.

```
selectEvent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
            ActivityA.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, ActivityA.INTENT_CODE);
        }
});

...
private static final int INTENT_CODE = 1;
...
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == INTENT_CODE)
    {
         Bundle extras = (data != null) ? data.getExtras() : null;
         myString = extras != null ? extras.getString("myKey"):null;
    }
}
```

To return data from ActivityB to ActivityA, don't call `startActivityForResult` on ActivityA.

In ActivityB, call [setResult() with result code and the intent containing the data to return](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29)

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra("myKey", selection);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
}
```